Custom Raspberry Pi Pico cannot upload .uf2 files and is not recognized as a COM device
I am facing an issue with my custom-designed Raspberry Pi Pico based on the RP2040. I followed the official documentation (Hardware Design with RP2040) to design the PCB, which I ordered via EasyEDA. However, I can’t get the Pico to work properly. Here are the details:
Problem:

When I connect the device, the typical mass storage appears with the two standard files (INDEX.HTM and INFO_UF2.TXT).
My PC does not recognize the device as a COM port.
Uploading a .uf2 file (e.g., blink.uf2 or flash_nuke.uf2) seems to succeed, but the file does not seem to be stored or executed.
After uploading, I cannot reconnect to the device using Thonny (or other tools) to install MicroPython or run a program.
I tried enabling the bootloader by connecting GND to the Flash memory pin, but this did not help. The mass storage only appears after I disconnect GND from Flash, but I still cannot upload anything.

Additional Information:

I followed the official Raspberry Pi hardware design guidelines while creating the PCB.
It seems like the device briefly boots, but none of the uploaded files are executed.
There are no visible issues with the PCB or the connections for me.
INFO_UF2.TXT:
UF2 Bootloader v3.0
Model: Raspberry Pi RP2
Board-ID: RPI-RP2



Question:
Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong? Did I possibly miss something during the PCB design? Are there other tests or methods to debug this issue? Thanks in advance for your help!
What I've Tried:

Uploading various .uf2 files (e.g., blink.uf2, flash_nuke.uf2).
Using Thonny to install MicroPython.
Manually booting the device by connecting GND to the Flash memory.
Installing and reinstalling different drivers on my windows pc (through Arduino IDE)


Your schematic got resized so it isn't legible.  There is probably some issue with how you connected the flash chip or the RUN button.  Or maybe you are uploading UF2 files that are not compatible with the RP2040; you should make sure those same files work on a Pico.
